# NSValueTransformer has been renamed to ValueTransformer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
class ArrayTransform : ValueTransformer { 

    override func  transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:value)
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: value as! Data)
    }

}
```

In the above code i am not able to override. So how can I implement it in Swift 3.0?

```
open class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool
open class func transformedValueClass() -> Swift.AnyClass
```

Autocomplete issue listed in the below snap.
[image]

Comment: Your code compiles fine. What's the problem?

Comment: I was able to get autoComplete for transformedValue: and reverseTransformedValue: , but for the mentioned methods it does not provide auto complete, I have to copy those method name from ValueTransformer and then it will give override error.

Comment: No it won't. Change "open" to "override" and add an implementation.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot for it. I also tried "override class func allow" , it does not work.

Comment: Would you stop obsessing about autocompletion? Just implement the methods, as demonstrated in my answer, and move on.

Answer (score 2):

Autocompletion doesn't have to work. The overrides *do* work. Just copy them in, like this:

```
class ArrayTransform : ValueTransformer { 

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> Swift.AnyClass {
        return NSData.self // or whatever
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true // or whatever
    }

    // ... your other overrides go here ...
}
```

Comment: It's pointless to downvote this. The code compiles and works, and that's what matters. If you don't like the lack of autocompletion, file a bug with Apple, but to obsess about it is just silly.